# How do I make the user provide me with the correct inputs?

Tags: python

```
site = input("Choose a site:\n 1.site1 2.site2")
while site!=1 and site!=2:
    print("Wrong input please choose between 1 and 2")
    site=input("Choose a site:\n 1.site1 2.site2")
```

Here I'm trying to make the user choose between the number 1 and the number 2 but for some reason I cant make it work, specifically when I use the correct numbers as input it wont get out of the while loop so the program can run,
I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
site = input("Choose a site:\n 1.site1 2.site2")
while True:
    if(site==1 or site==2):
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong input please choose between 1 and 2")
        site=input("Choose a site:\n 1.site1 2.site2")
```

Comment: In Python 3.x `input` returns a string, so comparing it to an integer doesn't make sense and will always return `False`.

Comment: Try converting the input to int.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to make it work for a while.

Comment: @toolic There's no point trying to convert it to an `int` before you verify the input is valid; check against strings, then call `int` on a known valid choice.

Comment: @chepner You are right, but I prefer to not call int at all instead verify the input using strings instead of integers because it throws an error if the user uses a string as an input,since the valid answer is either 1 or 2 it's not a problem using strings insted of integers.

Comment: @ppcase I'm not sure I follow. An input of `foo` should prompt the user for another input just as much as an input of `3`, rather than raising a `ValueError`.

Comment: @chepner i'm not refering to the solution of Ed Ward, I've tried running the following while giving an input of "foo"(note that i'm new to stackoverflow hence the link):https://controlc.com/cfc3481e

Comment: Related: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any input, you could try this function:

```
def enforced_input(prompt, options):
    if any([not type(i) == str for i in options]):
        raise ValueError("options should only contain string type")

    while True:
        result = input(prompt)
        if result in options:
            return result
        print("Please enter a valid input")
```

You can use it like this:

```
site = enforced_input("Choose a site:\n 1.site1 2.site2", ("1","2"))
```

Just remember that `input` returns a string, so make sure all your options are also strings, or it won't work.

Comment: Making `options` optional (or at least, this default value) doesn't make much sense. I'd rather get a traceback about a missing argument than a function that never returns.

Comment: good point... have edited

Answer (score 0):

By defualt `input()` takes input as `string` to take input as `int` you can use `int(input())` so your code will look like this

```
site = int(input("Choose a site:\n 1.site1 2.site2\n"))
while site!=1 and site!=2:
print("Wrong input please choose between 1 and 2")
site=input("Choose a site:\n 1.site1 2.site2\n")
```